# Dynamic HTML plus window.onload won't work on IE

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-events, onload

I'm having some difficulties about `window.onload` and it's like this:

I'm populating the innerHTML of a div using `jquery.magiclick.js` and fetching an xml, which has some img definitions, with an AJAX call. The function calls this `magiclick` function is resided in the document.ready like this:

```
$().ready(function () {
    loginBanner();
});
```

And I defined a `window.onload` function in another js. It's not needed but I'll include the code to make myself clearer. it simply calls the `window.onload` function if there is one defined previously and then the function passed as parameter. Here it goes:

```
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
      var oldonload = window.onload;
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.document.body.onload = function(){
            alert("onLoad-1");
            func();
        };
      } else {
            window.document.body.onload = function() {
                alert("onLoad-1");
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            };
      }
    }
```

I'm calling this function at the bottom of the page with a function parameter.

My expectation here is that it will fetch img definitions after the document is ready, and because the definitions include img references, it'll fetch the image data and then execute my `onload` function. It works great on Firefox but not on IE.

In IE, it's calling the `magiclick` function that fetches the xml then calling my `onload` function but at the time the `onload` function executes, xml file have not been fetched.

I'm stuck with that and any help will be deeply appreciated.

So, does anyone have an idea about what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous and does not have to be completed for your window load to fire

Call your code within the ajax success callback

Using jQuery AJAX shorthand method $.get() as example:

```
$.get( url, function(data){
  /* AJAX success, run  code here */
})
```

Comment: I'm actually calling a function in the callback where i populate the div's innerHTML. I'm inserting some img tags into it, so it should fetch the image data. are you saying that because ajax is asynchronous, so are my img definitions, and that causes the window.onload to fire before the images arrive. Am I right?
This is how I insert the img tag:
$('<div class="bannerBox"></div>').html('<img src="someImg"/>');

Can I define an onload function for those images?

Comment: yes, interpretation is correct. onload only knows about image tags that exist in source html. Do search in SO or google for image load methods